# CAML Query Maximum Size

Tags: spquery, caml-query

I am running a sharepoint caml query where I want to check that a field on an item is equal to one of many values. I do this dynamically and may wish to check against many hundreds of values.

I found that when performing a query with 780 OR elements I got an error related to server memory. Obviously this is variable across environments, but I am looking for some guidelines suggesting a maximum query length to which I should cap.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need those 780 OR statements? Can you paste part of your CAML Query?

Comment: I have a list with many folders (folders were required for security purposes). Each folder may have many items with in. I want to run a query such as: get all items from 600 of 800 folders. I am currently doing this by checking the FileRef field on the items with a very large nested OR caml query. If you have a better suggestion, by all means, PLEASE let me know

Comment: can't you do a recursive search to flatten the folders content ?

Comment: or create a view that does it and utilize that view/CAML.

Answer (score 3):

Or statements are notoriously inefficient, even directly in SQL. Since the error is related to memory it seems you're hitting a hardware limit rather than any kind of built-in limit.

With this in mind, I'd recommend using a more efficient query structure, such as the [`<In>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761.aspx) element to work around the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [U2U CAML Builder](http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) or [Stramit CAML Viewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/) to help build your CAML.  It seems like you might want to apply a content type filter instead of looking at every folder individually.

Answer (score 0):

Add a RowLimit element to your query to match your environment's list view threshold. Not sure how you are using the query, but its use may be circumventing the limit.

[RowLimit Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588460%28v=office.11%29.aspx)